# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined on Promise in Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have a route in my MEEN app that accepts a file upload, then passes the data to a helper module that parses the file and stores it in an array, once this helper module finishes I want to pass it off to another module that will then process the returned array. for some reason even though I have a return statement at the end of the helper the then method is undefined.

route:

```
router.route('/tools/sku/reactivate').post(upload.single('csvdata'),function(req,res){
        console.log('handing request over to helper.csv');
        csv.reader(req,res).then(sku.reactivate(data));
    });
```

csv.reader:

```
var csv = require('csv-parse');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.reader = function(req,res){
  //define array for holding csv data in this case skus
    const csvArray = [];
    //max number of columns in csv
    const maxColumns = parseInt(req.body.maxColumns);
    //create an array of column headers to check chunks against so we dont parse headers
    let columnHeader = req.body.moduleTarget.split(',');
    //loopThrough Array to create arrays inside container array for each column
    for(var i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++){
        csvArray.push([]);
    }
    //define filesystem readstream from uploaded file
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path).pipe(csv());
    //push csv data to array ignoring headers to csvArray
    readStream.on('data', function(chunk){
        //get number of keys in the dataChunk
        let chunkLength = Object.keys(chunk).length;
        //check column count on csv if greater than expected throw error
        if(chunk[maxColumns]){
            throw '[ERROR] More columns than expected in CSV, please fix and try again';
        }else{
            //loop through chunk keys and store each one in csvArray by index
            for(var i = 0; i < chunkLength; i++){
                //if chunk at this index doesnt equal column header and chunk at this index exists push to array
                if(chunk[i] !== columnHeader[i] && chunk[i]){
                    csvArray[i].push(chunk[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //error handling
    readStream.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file stream '+ err);
        res.json({message:err,errorType:'1'});
    });
    readStream.on('end',function(){
        console.log('finished reading csv returning array back to router to process next middleware');
        return csvArray;
    });
}
```

i get an error right after the console.log message on the readStream end listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Express website. https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html

TL;DR

Try wrapping the contents of your reader module inside a promise and return the promise.

*...However, there are two caveats:
All your asynchronous code must return promises (except emitters). If a particular library does not return promises, convert the base object by using a helper function like Bluebird.promisifyAll().
Event emitters (like streams) can still cause uncaught exceptions. So make sure you are handling the error event properly; for example:*

```
app.get('/', wrap(async (req, res, next) => {
  let company = await getCompanyById(req.query.id)
  let stream = getLogoStreamById(company.id)
  stream.on('error', next).pipe(res)
}))
```

@example:::

```
module.exports.reader = function(req,res){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      //define array for holding csv data in this case skus
        const csvArray = [];
        //max number of columns in csv
        const maxColumns = parseInt(req.body.maxColumns);
        //create an array of column headers to check chunks against so we dont parse headers
        let columnHeader = req.body.moduleTarget.split(',');

            ...
        //error handling
        readStream.on('error',function(err){
            console.log('Error while reading file stream '+ err);
            res.json({message:err,errorType:'1'});
        });
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            console.log('finished reading csv returning array back to router to process next middleware');
            return csvArray;
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: that did it, I also had my then syntax incorrect. thanks for the help copperpot

Comment: It's better not to pass `res` to `csv.reader()` and to compose the response back in the caller's `.then` and `.catch` handlers. This has particular advantages for any synchronously thrown errors arising from `csv.reader()`, which, as it stands, remain uncaught and unreported. To make the patttern is robust, be sure in both cases where `csv.reader()` rejects its Promise, that it does so with an `Error` object (or `RangeError` etc) - so the the eventual `.catch` handler, if called, is guaranteed to receive a proper error object (with a `.message` property), not a string.